# How does Cassandra write SSTable to disk?

Tags: cassandra

I have read some posts about Cassandra's work flow and now I am trying to look into the source code about SSTable.

In the `io` folder I found the "writer" and try to understand how it writes data to the disk. The folder includes a `SequentialWriter` that uses `RandomAccessFile` to write the data to the disk.

- Is this the writer that ultimately writes the SSTable to the disk?
- Are there any other files I should look into in order to understand it better?